# How do I prove the formula for multichoose?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

In combinatorics, there is a formula "$n$ multichoose $k$", which is the way of making a multiset having $k$ elements choosing out of $n$ options. "$n$ multichoose $k$" is the same as "$(n+k-1)$ choose $k$". Why is that?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking in how many $k$ objects can be selected from a multiset containing $n$ different types of objects?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html

Comment: See Theorem Two [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29); the explanation is quite clear.

Comment: @Taussig: what I have in mind is wolfram's example, someone who wants 5 pinches out of 9 spices

Comment: Somehow I explained where the formula comes from in an answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054808/combinatorics-number-of-possible-10-card-hands-from-superdeck-10-times-52-card) question. It is not a proof but rather the intuition.

Comment: There is an excellent tabular illustration in Knuth. TAOCP Volume 4A (Combinatorial Algorithms), section 7.2.1.3, Table 1 and its surrounding discussion do a superb job of teaching intuitively how a multichoose directly corresponds to a primal combination.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have $N$ items (all alike for now) and $K-1$ vertical bars (all alike for now).

How many unique ways can you line up the $N$ items and the $K-1$ vertical bars?

Now pretend that everything to the left of the first bar is Type $1$, everything between the first and second bar is Type $2$ ... and everything to the right of the last $(K-1)$th bar is Type $N$.

Do you see the connection?

Comment: I have seen this argument before, but it still isn't clear to me. I am learning from Ardila [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKskmKq3v40&list=PL-XzhVrXIVeSi7xym1XAfFIxOAaHVhjtP&index=3[/link] and he gives a proof from 5:30 from 7:30. Claiming a bijection between multichoose and weak compositions. Nevertheless, this bijection is not very clear to me